# How does a VPN client route traffic?

Tags: vpn, routing

Most likely noob question.

My Linux box reside in network 10.10.10.0/24 and I get working access to 192.168.1.0/24 via VPN. VPN client is started on the same box. However, when I perform `ip route show`, I see no new routes.

How is routing achieved?

Comment: Are you using an IPsec-based VPN client? Do you have anything unusual in `ip rule`?

Comment: ip rule returns:
_0: from all lookup local 220: from all lookup 220 32766: from all lookup main 32767: from all lookup default_
I use StrongSwan.

Comment: As you were looking for new routes, strongSwan installs routes (e.g. for virtual IPs) in table 220 by default, so try `ip route show table 220`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most other VPN software, IPsec clients on Linux use a *transform* system instead of tunnel interfaces. Your VPN packets still go to your default gateway as they did before, but strongSwan loads a set of transform policies into the kernel – causing it to "magically" encrypt the whole IP packet using ESP (and to change outer IP address to be your VPN gateway's) right before it's actually sent out.

See output of `ip xfrm policy` (templates provided by strongSwan) and `ip xfrm state` (actual rules  used for packets).

This system was originally meant for host-to-host and site-to-site encryption, and it certainly gets a little weird when client-based VPNs and 'virtual' IP addresses are involved. (There is actually a newly added tunnel-interface mode, 'xfrmi', which would make client-based VPN configurations more familiar – but it needs additional strongSwan settings to activate.)

---

Other VPN clients – such as OpenVPN, WireGuard, or OpenConnect – do create tunnel interfaces and would simply add an entry under 'ip route'.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation! And ip xfrm state indeed gives insight i was looking for.